# SQL: Display the value instead of ID

Tags: sql

I'm learning SQL and right now I'm trying to figure out one thing.

I have two tables

Products:

```
Product ID (PK) | ProductName
1               |  Apple
2               |  Pear
3               |  Orange
4               |  Banana
```

SalesOrderDetail:

```
SalesOrderID (PK) | Product ID | Quantity
1                 | 1          | 5
2                 | 3          | 4
3                 | 4          | 2
```

My question is - how do I display the name of the product in the second table instead of showing the ID?

Thank you.

Comment: it's the most basic join, have you tried something?

Comment: Please, before posting a question, have a look at the [tag info](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/sql/info), search for suggested references and resources.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `join`

```
select P.ProductName, S.SalesOrderID, S.Quantity
from Products P
join SalesOrderDetail S on S.Product_ID=P.Product_ID
```

[Here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp) you can find more information about joins.

Answer (score 0):

try this,use join

```
select sod.salesorderid,p.productname,sod.quantity from salesorderdetail sod
inner join products p 
on p.productid=sod.productid
```

Answer (score 0):

It will be

```
Select s.SalesOrderId, p.ProductName, s.Quantity from SalesOrderDetail s inner join Products p ON s.ProductID = p.ProductID
```

Answer (score 0):

For this, You can use the natural join available in SQL. If you are using MySQL, the code can be:

```
SELECT ProductName, ProductQuantity from Products NATURAL JOIN SalesOrderDetails;
```

OR

You can simply use the join operation as:

```
SELECT ProductName,ProductQuantity from Products p INNER JOIN SalesOrderDetails sd ON p.ProductId = sd.ProductId;
```

OR simply:

```
SELECT ProductName,ProductQuantity from Products p, SalesOrderDetails sd WHERE p.ProductId = sd.ProductId;
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
SELECT SOD.SalesOrderID
  ,P.ProductName
  ,SOD.Quantity 
FROM SalesOrderDetail SOD 
 ,Products P
WHERE P.ProductID=SOD.Product ID
```

Comment: Please use ANSI joins (`from a join b on ...`), they're less error prone.